# Grappling via Elemental's Blessing

Tags: grapple, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost-2e

Elemental's in 2e changeling have the blessing:

> As long as your character touches or is surrounded by his element, he may use it to take mundane actions at a distance of up to three yards (meters) away; these actions use his usual traits. This includes unarmed attacks, but not attacks with weapons.

So lets say my character is a plant-elemental in his greenhouse -- surrounded by his element of plant-life.

Someone comes to the door and knocks.
My character can slink down a vine of ivy to open the door handle.

But what if it turns out to be an enemy?
**Can my character wrap the ivy around him to grapple him?**
How does that go down?

Since grapple is a two way street, right?
So my enemy could grapple my character back, via grappling with the plants?
And even injury my character at range?

Answer (score 2):

Since a grapple counts as an unarmed attack, yes, your ivy could try to grapple him. 
And your enemy could grapple the IVY back or try to resist the grapple.

Your attack pool would be used, as per the rule you quoted. But that doesn't mean that you share your stats (Health levels for example) with the plant you're using. You don't gain the damage that is inflicted on the plant.

This means that your GM assigns a certain amount of Health Levels to your vine, proably not very many, and they take damage until they're done.